# How to add new Product Category in Opencart 2.1?

Tags: php, content-management-system, opencart2.x

I am going to add new product category into the current category list.I am using Opencart 2.1. Error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Following is the my code.

```
    public function addCategory($data) {
    $this->event->trigger('pre.admin.category.add', $data);

    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "category SET parent_id = '" . (int)$data['parent_id'] . "', `top` = '" . (isset($data['top']) ? (int)$data['top'] : 0) . "', `column` = '" . (int)$data['column'] . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$data['sort_order'] . "', status = '" . (int)$data['status'] . "', date_modified = NOW(), date_added = NOW()");

    $category_id = $this->db->getLastId();
```

Error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'.

I expect to add new product category in Opencart 2.1.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx7mM.png)

Comment: Error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: I don't see any Vb.net code. Please remove that tag.